# can you set an application to come to the desktop you are on osx

Tags: macos, system-settings, expose

I know that you can lock an application to a certain desktop, and if you select that application(either through the dock or command+tab), then OSX will change your desktop to the one where the application is on.

Can you set it to pull the application to you?

IE the messages.app.  I dont care where it is, but when I switch to it, I want it to come to me.

Im running 10.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign an application to 'All Desktops', then it will follow you around as you switch desktops, and no matter which desktop you're in when you click the dock icon or select it with CMD-TAB, the application will come to the forefront on the desktop you're at.